# apache on windows virtual directory config help

Tags: windows, apache, configuration, virtual-hosts

I'm running Apache on Windows XP via Xampplite, and could use help configuring my virtual directory. Here's what I'm hoping to do on my dev box:

1. I want my source files to live outside of the xampp htdocs dir
2. on my local machine I can access the project at http://myproject
3. others on my local network can access the project at my.ip.address/myproject
4. keep localhost pointing to the xampp's htdocs folder so I can easily add other projects.

I've got 1 & 2 working by editing the windows hosts file, and adding a virtual directory in xampp's apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf file. I don't immediately see how to do 3 without messing up 4.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Figured it out: use **Alias** for #3, instead of VirtualHost, thus:

```
Alias /myproject "C:/path/to/my/project"
<Directory "C:/path/to/my/project">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: For anyone unsure, this can go straight after `<Directory "D:/XAMPP/htdocs">...stuff...</Direcory>` in the `httpd.conf` file for the default site root. Worked for me perfectly. And don't forget to restart Apache

Answer (score 12):

### To accomplish your list of needs.

1) Make the directory:

> mkdir c:\xampp\sites\myproject

2) Edit c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts so it contains this line:

> 127.0.0.1         myproject

and add the following to c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

> ```
>   NameVirtualHost myproject:80
>
>   <VirtualHost myproject:80>
>   DocumentRoot c:/xampp/sites/myproject
>   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
>    AllowOverride All
>   Order allow,deny
>   Allow from all  
>   </Directory>
> ```

3) Add the following lines to the end of c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf:

> ```
>   Alias /myproject/  "/xampp/sites/myproject/"
>
>   <Directory "/xampp/sites/myproject">
>   AllowOverride None
>   Options None
>   Order allow,deny
>   Allow from all
>   </Directory>
> ```

4) Leave DocumentRoot, Directory, etc in c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf alone to accomplish this.  For reference these lines would be:

> ```
>   DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs"
>
>   <Directory />
>    Options FollowSymLinks
>    AllowOverride None
>    Order deny,allow
>    Deny from all
>   </Directory>
>
>   <Directory "/xampp/htdocs">
>    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
>    AllowOverride All
>    Order allow,deny
>    Allow from all
>   </Directory>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

First enable: LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

```
<IfModule alias_module>
  Alias /ddd "D:/prj/customer/www"

  <Directory "D:/prj/customer/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Tested on WAMP 2.2 and its working: http:// localhost/ddd

Answer (score 1):

In httpd.conf add the following lines, mutatis mutandis:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /angular-phonecat "C:/DEV/git-workspace/angular-phonecat"
</IfModule>

<Directory "C:/DEV/git-workspace/angular-phonecat">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This worked great on my (Windows) XAMPP installation after restarting the Apache server. I had to add the "Require all granted", but otherwise it is pretty much the same as the above answers.

Answer (score 0):

> NameVirtualHost myproject:80
>     < VirtualHost myproject:80 >
>   < /Directory >

Must be:

> NameVirtualHost myproject:80
>     < VirtualHost myproject:80 >
>   **< /VirtualHost >**

greets ;)

Answer (score 0):

resolved the issue. it was missing the directory tag.

```
NameVirtualHost myproject:80
<VirtualHost myproject:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Solution"
    <Directory "D:/Solution">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem resolved in a simplest way and less steps
No Need of creating virtual host just change the location of target directory.

Here's what i have done for configuration:
I've done it by editing the C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf file
Changings that I have done in httpd.conf file
Added this script right after
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/apache)/"

Alias /projectXYZ "C:/pathtomyproject"

  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

Pathtomyproject = Complete path of project

And changed the url of Document Root
DocumentRoot " C:/pathtomyproject "

Now restart the Apache Server by stopping the server.
I have stopped Apache server, and then again started the Apache Server.

Source: http://bytespedia.blogspot.com/2013/12/creating-virtual-directory-in-apache.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: as i was unable to attach picture so i have added link to complete description. @kleopatra

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Almo I have edited my comment and added the essential part of the solution/link.